# how can I pass value in setState to class constructor

Tags: flutter

I have Error at Over()
This is code:

```
  Offset _offset;
  GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (e) {
            Offset offset = e.globalPosition;
            setState(() {
              _offset = offset;
            });

   Positioned(
        left: size.width / 2,
        top: size.height / 2,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: Over(offset: _offset),
        ))
```

**Error** : The non-nullable local variable '_offset' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.dartnot_assigned_potentially_non_nullable_local_variable
Offset _offset

Comment: you should initialize the _offset with some default value. Because you are only providing it a value on "onTapDown" so, before it, it will be always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the below solutions:

**1. Use the late keyword**

```
class x{
  late Offset _offset; // No error
}
```

**2. Make variable nullable**

```
class x{
  Offset? _offset; // No error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the `_offset` variable ie. `Offset _offset = Offset(0,0)`